# Google vision API algorithm

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I was wondering how the google cloud vision works behind the scenes. What kind of algorithms are used for processing the images? Is there some texts explaining this?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a late answer, but adding it for future reference. As mentioned above the OCR is done through deep learning, especially the Convolutional Neural Networks. Do go though this blog by drop box on how they implemented their own OCR engine with similar workings.

https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2017/04/creating-a-modern-ocr-pipeline-using-computer-vision-and-deep-learning/

Comment: How do you know that? Any confirmation from Google that they use specifically Deep Learning and conv-nets for Vision OCR, as opposed to traditional approches like Tesseract, for example? Given that Tesseract development has been [sponsored by Google since 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)), the latter seems much more likely to me. The blog post you linked above is by Dropbox, not Google, and talks about their mobile application, not a cloud-based solution like Google Vision.

Answer (score 1):

Its more or less a Deep Neural Network at the back end, which is doing all this possible, through the Cloud, again part of Machine Learning process.

Comment: @AlessandroVisintin, if you are satisfied with the answer, vote this answer

Comment: I have already voted, but my experience is too low and stack overflow is not going to add my preference, sorry